# jQuery - jump to first div class on anchor click

Tags: jquery, class

I want to use jQuery animate to jump to the first occurrence of a class on the page, at the moment I am using some basic code but I get an error in the console when I fire the onclick event.

This is my HTML with RAZOR:

```
@model List<Business.Models.InterviewCentres.InterviewCentresViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Interview Centre Bookings</h2>
<br />
The website is now showing dates between <b>@DateTime.Now.AddDays(21).ToShortDateString()</b>
and <b>@DateTime.Now.AddDays(92).ToShortDateString()</b>
@{
    string previousLocation = "";
}
<!-- get each unique location and add to list. Will use this to build clickable links -->
@{

    List<string> Locations = new List<string>();
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (!Locations.Contains(item.Location))
    {
        Locations.Add(item.Location);
    }
}
<br />
@foreach (string location in Locations)
{
    <a href="#" class="lnkNav"><span style="color: #772432; border-bottom-style: dotted;">@Html.Raw(location)</span>
        &nbsp</a> 
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label(item.CentreDateLocation)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("InterviewCentreInfo", "InterviewCentres", new { date = item.DateOfInterview.ToString(), centre = item.Location })">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/excel.gif")" alt="Export grid data to excel" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var times in item.ListDateMemberNum)
            {
                if (previousLocation != item.Location)
                {
                    previousLocation = item.Location;
                <hr />
                }

                <td>
                <div class = "@item.Location.Trim()">
                    @if (times.MemberNumber == "")
                    {   <div style="background-color: rgb(242, 246, 243); display: inline-block; padding-top: 2px;
                        padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                        @Html.Raw("&nbsp")
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/cross.gif")" alt="cross" />
                        @Html.Label(times.InterviewDate + " | ")
                    </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div style="background-color: rgb(242, 246, 243); display: inline-block; padding-top: 2px;
                            padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                            @Html.Raw("&nbsp")
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/tick.gif")" alt="tick" />
                            <a href="@Url.Action("LookupPassword", "Membership", new { MemberNum = times.MemberNumber })" style="background-color:Red; color:White;">@times.InterviewDate</a>
                        </div>
                    }
                    </div>
                </td>   
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<script>
    $('.lnkNav').click(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("." + text).offset().top
        },
        'slow');
    });
</script>
```

When I click on an anchor of class .lnkNav I get the text of the clicked anchor which is also the name of the class that I want to navigate to. However it doesn't work. I've added some screenshots to show that there are anchors with text and there are classes with the same name. Anybody know how I would implement this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You shoulda check the `$('.' + text )` is defined. After that, you can focus it.

```
$('.lnkNav').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if ($("." + text).length != 0) {
        $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("." + text).offset().top
            },
        'slow');
    } else {
        alert (" element not found!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey I tried your code and it goes into the else block. I'm sure my classes are named correctly so I am not sure why the if condition doesn't work.